# Dupe target is unconcise

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68414115/what-to-use-instead-of-display-block-at-a-breakpoint-css), which essentially asks how to hide an element in CSS. The question shows low effort, low grammar quality, and little usability due to being centered around an extremely fundamental topic.

Someone closed the question as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598568/how-to-display-and-hide-a-div-with-css). I heartily agree with the action of closing this as a duplicate, but not as much with the dupe target itself.

The title of the dupe target sounds very promising. It sounds much like one of those decade-old multi-thousand-vote canonicals that drive people to SO. But further inspection proves otherwise.

- **Complicated:** This question and its answers involve use of the `visibility` property, the tilde `~` selector, property inheritance, and comma usage. These are quite simple topics when discussed succinctly in their own post ([observe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782054/what-does-the-tilde-squiggle-twiddle-css-selector-mean)), but combined make this an overly confusing dupe target unlikely to help the OP.

Chances are if you are unsure about hiding an element in CSS, you might struggle to make heads or tails of this question. It may have been a long day for me, but even I struggle to comprehend it.

- **Not reproducible:** The entire problem in the question was actually caused by [what could be considered to be] a typo: an improper comma.
- **Unclear in purpose**: The answers don't even interpret the question in the same way. The accepted answer simply writes code to solve the OP's problem (the typo), the next gives a list of ways to hide an element, and the last writes a jQuery function.

I'm slightly unsure of my call to action here, but I suppose I wanted a second opinion on this dupe target. Is it confusing? Is it more efficiently represented in separate posts? Why is is so highly upvoted?

Comment: `Page not found` for the link of the question you came across.

Comment: @Galen - of course. It was removed by the author voluntarily, now only 10K+ users can see it

Comment: I can update the question to include more details, but my summary is all that's really necessary. The point is more about the dupe target. Someone is bound to ask about hiding an element in the future, and when they do, someone could use this dupe target again.

Comment: That answer on the dupe [How to display and hide a div with CSS?](//stackoverflow.com/a/24055535) explains what one needs to know without any other fluff like `~`. So I would consider it a suitable dupe. Regarding *"Unclear in purpose"* ... those answers provide different ways to hide elements, so that Q&A is even more usable as a dupe target.

Comment: The original duplicate was for a disjointed rollover, so I agree with your assessment that it wasn't an ideal duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, the question is unclear and likely to be closed so I decided to close it as duplicate with a related question that can give some hint to the OP about his problem.

Now the OP is required to either edit his question to add more detail about the issue in case the duplicate is not suitable or to accept the duplicate if it's suitable but what happened: The OP simply repeated the same unclear question: [what to use instead of display block at a breakpoint css?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68414944/8620333)

This time I decided to close it as **Needs debugging details** (unlear and lack focus also apply)

Comment: We'll create a new "Fastest Hammer in the West" term just for you.

Comment: @Kaiido I will take it ;)