# Is Stack Overflow useful for getting help on "duplicate" questions, or is there another community (or part of Stack Overflow?) people would recommend?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions

I've only used Stack Overflow a few times, and I'm trying to understand the etiquette/purpose.

I asked a question today but my question was nearly instantly marked as duplicate. The mod/admin person who flagged it as duplicate was right though! I *was* asking a question about a very common topic.

However, the level of expertise/experience in the linked question was beyond my ability to comprehend (or maybe it's not actually what I need, I'm still trying to work that problem out). I was asking for basic guidance or maybe a link to further reading/resources. Or if I was lucky, a helpful stranger might give me a paragraph or two explaining how to address my problem specifically!

But now my question is closed, so there is zero chance anyone can respond.

If Stack Overflow is only for wiki/Q&A Knowledgebase style content, and not "helping some stranger who has a question"... could anyone please suggest a resource more suitable for general programming community help?

I'm not trying to rant or be bitter, I understand the value in pruning a site's content to only keep high-value content... better for search results, better for readers in the future, centralize knowledge, etc. And my question WAS a duplicate. But I'm wondering if other sites exist which -do- allow for duplicates / informal help. Or perhaps a partner/subsection of Stack Overflow?

Comment: You could reformulate your question in such a way that links to the duplicate, shows what you tried according to that duplicate, and explains (in detail) what went wrong or what you don't understand from there

Comment: Thanks @Tomerikoo I'll give that a go (after I spend more time researching the topic and if I still need help)

Comment: How do you know the duplicate target is correct if you don't understand the duplicate target?

Comment: This question is answered by the [tour] and the [help], as well as some existing questions here on Meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381992/whats-the-precise-and-exact-mission-statement-of-stack-overflow & https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292175/what-is-the-purpose-of-stack-overflow. In short, you can still ask questions to get help here (that's a necessary function of building a Q&A repository), but the overall goal is to have everyone's *good* questions and answers preserved and maintained for all time.

Comment: If you don't overstep boundaries, you can also ask in [chat rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/?tab=site&host=stackoverflow.com) dedicated to the programming language/technology. A lot of users hang around there, and we are usually a friendly bunch (unless the message is a post dumped into a room). But be careful to ask (or read if available) for room rules first.

Comment: I believe if you hit such case (your question is answered but you can't understand the answer) is in most cases means you've reached the boundaries of what can be generally explained on internet posts/books and need one-on-one education session. Pretty much all novice topics (like recursion, variables, method calls, using command line tools,...) require either someone figuring what works for you to understand or you reading essentially all available explanations till one clicks... SO is really not setup for this type of explanation.

Comment: "could anyone please suggest a resource more suitable for general programming community help" I'm really serious when saying that in general resources like books, tutorials, courses and the like are your best bet. When having "a question about a very common topic" it's best to start reading a lot instead of asking. What you basically ask for here (personal tutoring for free) exists nowhere, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Trilarion Well, places like Codementor.io do exist...

Comment: *"I was asking for basic guidance or maybe a link to further reading/resources"* that's a problem.  That's off-topic for this site.  That's why you have to show why your particular question isn't necessarily a direct duplicate.  Asking for examples or tutorials is not what this site is for.

Comment: You may need or benefit from a mentor. There are online platforms that facilitate this, if you don't have someone in the offline world.

Comment: @TylerH There might be some places but I guess that their capacity is not sufficient by far to satisfy the demand for high quality free online tutoring. Effectively everyone will have to learn by themselves a lot. We could though assemble a list of such places in an answer.

Comment: "But I'm wondering if other sites exist which -do- allow for duplicates / informal help" - pretty much the same list I posted here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/409391/424903 . And Google will know others.

Comment: Reddit has some communities for each language, and people there usually help. Check some posts of [r/csharp](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp), for instance.

Comment: If you don't understand one or more of the answers, drop a comment asking for clarification! If you didn't understand an answer, chances are pretty good someone else missed it too. It helps everyone if you ask good, informed questions or for clarifications as long as you've given understanding things a good shot first.

Comment: I can't necessarily speak to the identity of Stack Overflow, but I actually *did* recently [call out a very similar problem here on Meta about complicated duplicates.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409192/dupe-target-is-unconcise)

Comment: Relevant: [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046) It mentions your "own questions", but most of the same advice applies with someone else's question (you obviously shouldn't add your own progress updates in there though). Unfortunately trying to getting new or improved answers on an old question isn't always that easy.

Comment: Did you research Stack Overflow before posting your question?  Did you already discover the nominated duplicate while you were searching?  How could Servy know that the nomination would not serve your knowledge level?  Every time this type of question comes up, I recommend that askers include any related pages that they found but were not ultimately helpful.  This gives the question better context/scope and should prevent curators from using those pages as duplicates.  This also signals to the community that old pages need to be better explained.

Comment: The worst thing about the dupe mechanic is that it assumes a static universe where what was a good answer 4 years ago is still a good answer. I'm not a fan.

Comment: @HansKilian Or duplicate closure assumes that answers will be updated to reflect more recent developments. That already happens sometimes and Stack Overflow Inc is trying to increase how often that happens, so I guess we'll see how that goes. In principle one of the worst things you can do on a repository of knowledge such as SO is have 1000 copies of the same question, each of which reflects a different period in time, and only 1 of which is current. Anyone coming through Google could land on any of those and get outdated information.

Comment: *so there is zero chance anyone can respond* - people can still comment, and do. I often leave a comment, after dupe-closing a question, to guide as to how the duplicate target advice might be adjusted to fit your context.

Comment: @HansKilian amen, or ones like "What is a null reference exception and how do I fix it" where 25 people have had a go at explaining it in such micro-navel-fluff detail that it's a darned book of its own

Comment: @inter Try here https://dev.to/

Comment: Ultimately, the misconception/confusion about the mission of Stack Overflow lies in the collision of activities from curators trying to build an elegant/effective/lean knowledge base versus new users thinking that their individual needs are more important than the needs of the whole.  If this is ever going to be remedied, there needs to be a change in marketing, but that will make SO as an organization seem less welcoming (bad for profits) -- whereas now, it just seems like the volunteers are the unwelcoming ones. Closing duplicates is not a punishment - it is a resolution that prevents bloat.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov "...or you reading essentially all available explanations till one clicks." Well said, I'm glad it's not just me who had to do this. To add to this, it's not that I wouldn't love to give somebody the perfect explanation that saves somebody all that reading, I've definitely tried many times over the years. It's just not that easy to transfer "expertise". I can't completely explain why, it's just the way we learn, it's been the same way for when I learned art, music, anything; you have to internalize the knowledge.

Comment: @Trilarion to your "reading books" logic, a book might not be the best resource for someone who isn't sure what to look for -- and then some people learn by asking rather than "reading a lot". Also, for a better welcoming experience on Q/A (and free tutoring), there's reddit, Quora and colleagues.

Comment: @samkart A book doesn't require supervision and is simply the cheapest options. If reading is not for you you have to ask and rely on the availability and goodwill of people to teach you for free. I guess my thesis is that this doesn't really scale well. Of course one can try. I have nothing against Quora or Reddit.

Comment: @HansKilian "The worst thing about the dupe mechanic is that it assumes a static universe where what was a good answer 4 years ago is still a good answer. I'm not a fan." But often enough they are, and in case they aren't one can probably ask the question in a way that explains why the answers to that other question are inadequate. (There must be a reason for it. It may be possible to include that reason in the question.)

Comment: Perhaps we should have ephemeral sites (that would be deleted (domain name removed from DNS) on a regular basis, like every year) where new users could ask the same questions over and over. `dupe2021.stackoverflow.com`, `dupe2022.stackoverflow.com`, `dupe2023.stackoverflow.com`, ad infinitum. There would be warnings in advance - *"dupe2021.stackoverflow.com is going to wiped off the Internet in 13 days and 17 hours. Do you want to post to dupe2021.stackoverflow.com?"*. There could be annual reports - *"In 2022, we saved the Internet from 1,341,221 duplicate questions."*

Comment: @PeterMortensen I'm hoping you're joking. If not, well, that would go directly against Stack Overflow's mission, the mission of the World Wide Web ["Cool UR\[L\]s don't change"](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html) and one of the reasons both are so well loved. As a consultant, I'm often pulled into projects when they find out the code base they've inherited is 10 years old. I want those old questions and answers to stay around so that I can get the answers I need quickly.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The "Asking" section of the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) has some really good content, which should give a good starting picture of the "purpose" of the site (as you put it).  In particular, [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) are a good reference.

> I was asking for basic guidance or maybe a link to further reading/resources.

This site tends to be about specific, focused, practical questions with straightforward answers.  Unfortunately for your case, neither basic guidance nor links to further reading are within its purview.

> If Stack Overflow is only for wiki/Q&A Knowledgebase style content, and not "helping some stranger who has a question"... could anyone please suggest a resource more suitable for general programming community help?

I think you're right that it's not a forum for general programming help.  What it is, and what I encourage you to continue using it as, is a resource for specific, focused questions.  When you do have such questions, and they truly have not been answered yet, this is definitely the right resource.

Though I will warn you that if your question is particularly niche, you may or may not end up getting any actual help, though I find the process of whittling down my problem for asking the specific question often leads me to a solution.  In this case, I like to post a [self-answered](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) question with my solution.  Not only is it a good way to pay it forward for future users with the same question, I've also found it a good resource for myself several years and multiple projects down the road when I end up with the exact same question in a similar but different context, and I discover my own answer from several years back.

Finally, I wouldn't be too disheartened by the duplicate.  Some times even after a question search it's not obvious there's a duplicate, especially if you don't know the terminology used.  Having a question closed as a duplicate in this situation can still be beneficial.  First, it points you at the actual answer.  Second, future searchers who were thinking in the same context as yourself have your duplicate question as a signpost to the original question when they also are thinking of the question in a different context than the original.

> But I'm wondering if other sites exist which -do- allow for duplicates / informal help. Or perhaps a partner/subsection of Stack Overflow?

I don't think there's anything in Stack Exchange which addresses this need.  I don't personally know what sites would be good for this purpose, so I'll leave answering that to the more well informed.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful advice (both this answer, and your answer regarding my original programming question). I like the idea of self-answered questions too.

Comment: "and I discover my own answer from several years back" did you try to upvote it?

Comment: @Braiam You know it.   I think I tried to upvote one of my own answers within the last week, in fact.

Comment: "But I'm wondering if other sites exist which -do- allow for duplicates / informal help" discord and reddit are great

Comment: I'll admit this is me being a bit pedantic, but… Saying "Discord" is a good place for getting informal help is like saying "The Internet" is.  It's technically true, but it's also not a unified whole and you'd need to find the right channel(s).  Similar for Reddit.

Comment: @M.Justin At least Reddit has some fairly obvious places to start - most frameworks and languages have at least one subreddit. Discord, on the other hand, has no centralized directory.

Comment: @aheze I would less say that "discord and reddit are great" for allowing duplicates, and more that allowing dupes is *required* because content churns so quickly on those platforms

Comment: Heck, I *regularly* attempt to upvote my own content when I land on it, in part just to make sure the system check guarding against that is still working...

Comment: @GammaGames Indeed, perhaps the most frustrating thing about Reddit is that all threads there are permanently locked after 6 months. It would be great if subreddits were able to set different (or no) limits.

Answer (score 19):

Looking at your closed question ([How can I make my own "foreach" or similar for my 2D array of custom objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68625551/how-can-i-make-my-own-foreach-or-similar-for-my-2d-array-of-custom-objects)), I'm personally not convinced it's a duplicate of ([Pass Method as Parameter using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082615/pass-method-as-parameter-using-c-sharp)).  It may be a solution, or even the "obvious" solution, to your question, but I think your question is distinct enough to stand on its own.

If I'm interpreting this correctly, your question is really two parts: how do you flatten the array so you can do the `foreach`, and how do you pass in the command to that array.  *Maybe* it is a duplicate of both halves, but it's concise and well defined enough that I personally would treat it as its own question, especially since there may be solutions that don't make sense for the whole that do for the parts, or vice versa.

That said, I think the vagueness of your question works against you in this regard.  What I find helpful in this sort of situation is to create a short yet fully reproducible dummy implementation that captures the issue, and which if answered I could apply to my real issue.  I think you're mostly there, but I would, for instance, define your `Levels` type, replace `some logic here` with something concrete on this type (e.g. if `Levels.isBonus()` or something), etc.  The example would still be super terse, but you would communicate your exact requirement in a way that anybody could copy/paste into their own development environment and give you a concrete answer about.

If it were me, I might edit the question to make it concrete, and possibly also explain how the suggested duplicate isn't an exact fit for your situation.  If editors agree that your changes make your question stand on its own, or that your clarifications address things that led to it looking like a duplicate, they may vote to reopen it.

Comment: As I understand it, the OP's issue is that using `for` over a 2D array each time creates a lot of boilerplate code, and the OP is looking for a way to reduce that boilerplate. One way to do this is to wrap the `for` code in a method taking a delegate, as in the duplicate source. But another way is to write an iterator method which returns the element and its indices at each iteration (perhaps as a value tuple), which would enable `foreach`. This technique is irrelevant to the duplicate source; and I would therefore argue the question is not a duplicate.

Comment: I don't think that the specific question that was closed (and whether it was rightly closed) are particularly relevant.  The OP of this meta question has asked this as a **general** question about the handling of dup questions ... and about getting help using Stack Overflow.

Comment: @StephenC, the specific question on SO is very much relevant. It was closed by someone who was being overly strict and aggressive about their own interpretation of what constitutes a valid question. Sadly, that's a common reason that questions are closed. And that needs to be part of any answer to the meta question. In other words, just because something is marked "duplicate" doesn't mean it is. The OP could certainly have phrased it better, but the one who really deserves a penalty is Servy. Unfortunately the culture of SO rewards smug dismissals or at least allows people to get away with it.

Comment: @Angelo - Seriously?  The OP himself wrote this in the meta question: *"The mod/admin person who flagged it as duplicate was right though! I was asking a question about a very common topic."*   If the OP **himself** thinks that his question was **correctly** closed as a duplicate ... then what you are talking about is OTHER questions.   And that's off-topic for this Q&A.

Comment: @StephenC Responding to your prior comment about whether the specific question is relevant, I think it is so far as much of the underlying assumptions coloring the OP's question stem from the perception that the question was a duplicate.  That said, I'd agree that the general questions being asked here are completely valid regardless of whether or not this particular question was rightly closed as a duplicate.  So I guess… I almost completely agree with your point, though I think it's a useful and relevant enough side discussion to be included as its own answer (which is why I wrote it).

Comment: @StephenC yes, "seriously". The ultimate issue here is that MANY question are closed, recklessly, without regard to whether they're *actually* duplicates. The answer to the OP should be that he just needs to rephrase his question so that the self-appointed "dupe-police" don't give him a "ticket" because the question sort-of overlaps with some dense canonical answer the dupe-police has in mind. Oh, and by the way, the original question is open now, so whether or not it's a dupe is very much in question.

Comment: @Angelo - You are missing my point.  THIS meta question is not about THAT issue.  If you want to discuss THAT issue, post a DIFFERENT meta question.  And provide some hard evidence.  Like a scientific sampling that provides quantitative evidence of how much inappropriate dup-hammering goes on.  (I assume that you want to be taken seriously ... so do the research and post the question.)

Answer (score 15):

No, Stack Overflow isn't useful for getting help on already asked very common topics in an informal way. The primary purpose of Stack Overflow is to serve the billions of times readers are coming to the site with clear, focused information. The millions of askers profit from it only if they can create a question that is clear, focused and well researched.<sup>1</sup>

That includes that Stack Overflow is not a free tutoring service.<sup>2</sup> If you find yourself wanting to ask questions about very common topics often that is a strong sign that you should increase your learning efforts from more traditional sources (books, tutorials, courses) that do not require supervision. You should also try to improve your searching skills in order to better find resources on the Internet. And you can practice your coding skills with numerous coding challenges or just by yourself. You don't really need a community in order to learn programming.

If it happens that you still have a question after reading and searching a lot and you are fairly sure that it hasn't been asked before, of course you can and should ask it here. Reading on Stack Overflow is absolutely recommended but asking here can also be a nice addition to your learning, especially with obstacles you may have. I have asked on Stack Overflow and additionally to countless hours of reading that has helped me a lot.

Of course, if you prefer a more mentoring/tutoring kind of approach you can search for paid such services or try something like https://www.codementor.io/ (mentioned by TylerH) or other educational sites with less strict requirements (https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/, https://programming1.quora.com/?share=1, ...) but the quality of them may vary. I'm not aware of a site that I could really recommend.

---

<sup>1 - Of course it can happen that a question is asked multiple times (search isn't perfect) but even then the asker gets an answer. In the case that a question is falsely marked as duplicate (mistakes happen too) questions can even be re-opened and if that works then the asker would get an answer.</sup>

<sup>2 - And the reason for that is simply that it doesn't scale well, I think. A free tutor service will need a number of tutors proportional to the number of students, a knowledge library like Wikipedia or Stack Overflow however, will only need a constant number of experts, regardless of the number of knowledge consumers. One would need to pay for a tutoring service to get good quality or start self-help groups.</sup>

Comment: "... the billions of readers ..." hmmm....

Comment: RE:"questions can even be re-opened and the asker may get an answer. " That tends to be nearly impossible. Once something is marked duplicate it is almost certainly destined to die there. Also my possibly naïve opinion it shouldn't even be allowed to use a very old question as a source to mark as a dupe.

Comment: @4386427 More like page visits. Something like 50 billion visits so far but some people come and read more often. Could also be less than a billion unique visitors, nobody really knows. Still the number of readers is several orders of magnitude higher than the number of askers.

Comment: @Preston Yes, it's difficult but that's the theory. If a question is not a duplicate, people will eventually realize it and first reopen the question and then answer it. In practice this may not work so well.

Comment: Given that there's less than 8 billion people on the planet, and only about 5 billion of them are Internet users, and it's a safe guess that significantly less than 1/5 of them are involved with a field that would bring them to the Stack Exchange family of sites, I think it's safe to say there's not billions of readers.

Comment: @Preston "*Also my possibly naïve opinion it shouldn't even be allowed to use a very old question as a source to mark as a dupe*" this is doable if people stop asking things that were explained again and again a very long time ago. Until then, if they ask for something that has a canonical from 2010, we should be using that as the dupe target.

Comment: @Trilarion To me the exact number of readers isn't a big deal but .... no, SO doesn't have a billion readers.

Comment: @M.Justin "Given that there's less than 8 billion people on the planet..." I could argue that some readers of SO will already have died, so the real upper limit on the number of SO unique visitors is a bit larger than the current population of the the planet but yeah, you're right. The only number there is is the number of visits of the questions  which is on the order of 50 billion. Now it all comes down to how often someone on average visits the site.

Comment: @Trilarion If it doesn't work in practice then perhaps it shouldn't be leaned on for answers to posts like this?

Comment: @Preston Oh, it works in practice to at least some extent. I have helped to reopen questions and they got reopened. It's not working that bad that I wouldn't mention it anymore. To be on the safe side, I changed the wording slightly.

Comment: @Trilarion fair enough, I've had significant trouble with it previously to the point that I just gave up and got my answers elsewhere.

Comment: @Trilarion You really think that more than one in ten people on the planet visit Stackoverflow?  Closer to one in ten *thousand* I'd venture.  Honestly I just stopped reading your baloney right then and there.

Comment: @Dexygen No, I don't think this. I think it's rather unlikely but I also think that readers of that answer get the gist. Of course you can stop reading at any time. I have nothing against it.

Answer (score 15):

I agree with [Oleg Valter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/11407695/oleg-valter)'s comment on OP. I think it deserves to be conserved as an answer. Here it is:

> If you don't overstep boundaries, you can also ask in [chat rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/?tab=site&host=stackoverflow.com)
> dedicated to the programming language/technology. A lot of users hang
> around there, and we are usually a friendly bunch (unless the message
> is a post dumped into a room). But be careful to ask (or read if
> available) for room rules first.